# How to "remove diacritics" from UTF8 characters in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I need to replicate the behavior of MySQL `utf8_general_ci` collation in PHP. Strictly speaking I need to detect what whould be considered different and what would be considered the same. The case independent part is easy. The problem is `utf_general_ci` considers characters with diacritics and characters without diacritics to be equal: e = è = é etc.. To replicate that comparison, I'd need to have a way to replace è -> e, é -> e.

The method that comes to my mind is:

```
echo iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT", "é");
```

One problem is `iconv` behaves differently depending on current locale and that's asking for a problem.

The other problem is the input may also contain Cirillic letters that shouldn't be stripped or result in a PHP Notice.

```
echo iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT", "дом");
```

Is there a solution or do I have to create manually mapping of each character with diacritic to a one without it?

Comment: Please back up a step and explain why you need to strip accents and why you must do it in PHP.

Comment: I need to bulk insert some values and I must be sure all of them won't collide with the values already present in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

intl's [Transliterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php) will let you define far more in-depth transliteration rules. The full documentation on transliteration rules can be found on [icu-project.org](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general).

```
$tests = [ "é", "дом" ];

$tl = Transliterator::create('Latin-ASCII;');
foreach($tests as $str) {
    var_dump(
        $tl->transliterate($str)
    );
}
```

Output:

```
string(1) "e"
string(6) "дом"
```

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to 'prevent collisions values already present in the table'?  And there are accented letters that should be allowed to coexist with different accents and non-accents?  Then change the collation of the `PRIMARY` (or `UNIQUE`) key that is causing the collisions.

Any `..._bin` `COLLATION` will allow `e` and `é` to coexist (not collide during insertion) because it treats them as different.

Do you need `...general_ci` for some other reason?  If so, please state the reason.  If not, `ALTER TABLE` to change the `COLLATION`.  I see no need for PHP code.

Comment: No, accented letters should not be allowed to coexist with not accented ones. There is utf8_general_ci on the the table and it's there to stay. Let's call it bussiness requirement for simplicity.
So if there is "mere" in the table and I try to insert "mére" I receive a DB error. Handling DB errors, particularly if I do a bulk insert is unwieldy, so I want to detect such error in advance. Therefore in PHP.

Comment: Contradiction:  "requirement for simplicity" versus standing on your head to get around it.

Comment: You keep misquoting me or quoting out of context. You fail to understand "replication of comparison" and "bussiness requirement". That's trolling, not helping. PLONK