# Can PHP mimic MySQL utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci collation?

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, collation

I have a table in MySQL:

```
results
-----------
word   VARCHAR(200) UNIQUE [collation: utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci]
count  INT
```

I have a PHP script that aggregates word+count tuples, but it must do so in a way that matches the `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` collation. This is because the results of this aggregation will be inserted into the table, and I must prevent duplicates.

```
$tuples = [
   "Cafe"=>5,
   "Cafe"=>1,
   "Café"=>3,
   "Café"=>4,
];
// Should result in:
//     ["Café"=>13"]  <-- picks the version with the most counts: Café
// AND NOT
//     ["Cafe"=>6, "Café"=>7]  <-- these will be treated as duplicates in MySQL
$results = aggregateCounts($tuples);
```

In this example, I could have PHP group the tuples by replacing `é` with `e` -- but I would prefer to mimic exactly what MySQL does to determine if characters are duplicates, given the collation of `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.

How do I go about doing this?

The only foolproof solution I can think of is to perform the aggregation in MySQL itself -- this is unfortunately not possible in my use case given the size of the data I will be aggregating.

Comment: 1. PHP does not seem to have an "accent-insensitive" comparison function. 2. You could write one yourself using a [Transliterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48589353/1064767). 3. MySQL is going to be far better suited to performing large-scale aggregations than anything written in PHP. I would suggest describing _that_ problem in a MySQL-focused question.

Comment: If you ever [think of] writing SQL in a tight loop (except to separate large batches), you have a problem that is either a) missing understanding of SQL, or b) data not structured to use. This generalization that may attract other exceptions.

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks for finding that question -- it appears to be a dupe of mine. I will look into Transliteration.  I'm not actually doing aggregation, I used this simply as an example -- but I have to disagree that MySQL is better suited for "large-scale" aggregations. For instance, if I want to simply agg counts contained in logs or CSV files (100s of GBs) I'm probably better off streaming the file to my own process and aggregating there.

Comment: @danblack This is good advice, but seems to not be applicable to my example which contains no loops, or SQL for that matter.

Comment: "replacing é with e" -- MySQL does not do that.  It goes through an algorithm that says that they are "equal".  There are more complex cases:  a `e` and an acute accent that is non-spacing.  That pair of codepoints are considered equal to `e`.  Etc.  Please elaborate on why you want the feature; maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: @RickJames My comment explains the reasoning -- given a set of strings I need to know which ones will be "equal" according to a specifc MySQL collation, so that when I insert I do not get duplicates.

Comment: @JS_Riddler - Or... Perform the `INSERT`, let MySQL complain, then take evasive action when the INSERT fails.

Comment: @RickJames Please, read the question. If I were to wait until the INSERT to detect the error, my entire aggregation would be incorrect and would be rendered a waste of time. Furthermore, there is no "evasive action" I can take. The "evasive action" is to treat strings the same that MySQL will -- hence the question.